# Looping Through Subdirectories and Running a Command in Each

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

I have a set of repositories sorted into directories based on their VCS (Git, Mercurial, SVN). With Subversion I was able to run `svn update *` in the parent directory and it would loop through each directory and update each repository as expected. That's not the case for Git or Mercurial.

I would like to come up with a bash script that I can run to do exactly that, loop through directories and either `git pull` or `hg pull` in each. I just don't have much bash scripting experience.

Comment: It could be clarified whether you want the commands executed recursively (in all subfolders), where mj41's answer is the only one I've tried (from here and at other SO sites) that does that.

Comment: * does that with a tweak that I mention in a comment on it.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
for dir in ~/projects/git/*; do (cd "$dir" && git pull); done
```

Comment: Thnx... but i need to capture errors as well. How can I do so. I've never done shell programming before.

Comment: If I remove parenthesis it stops working. What's the concept behind it?

Comment: @mohit parentheses create a sub-shell where the commands are executed, so the `cd` will descend into the given directory and then when the sub-shell exits you'll be back in the original directory.

Answer (score 30):

If you need it to be recursive:

```
find . -type d -name .git -exec sh -c "cd \"{}\"/../ && pwd && git pull" \;
```

This will descend into all the directories under the current one, and perform a git pull on those subdirectories that have a .git directory (you can limit it with `-maxdepth`).

Comment: @thprivileges: clever!

Comment: `-execdir` is much better here: `find . -type d -name .git -execdir sh -c "pwd && git pull" \;`

Comment: This is a better answer in my subjective opinion... Worked immediately for me.. Cheers

Comment: Unlike the question that linked me here, this command actually worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

If you have GNU Parallel http:// [www.gnu.org/software/parallel/](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) installed you can do this:

```
cd ~/projects/git/; ls | parallel 'cd {} && git pull'
```

This will run in parallel so if some of the git servers' network connection are slow this may speed up things.

If the dir listing is < 128 KBytes, you can also do:

```
parallel 'cd {} && git pull' ::: ~/projects/git/*/
```

If you want to follow the pull happening (requires version 20230322):

```
parallel --ll 'cd {} && git pull' ::: ~/projects/git/*/
```

Watch the intro video for GNU Parallel to learn more:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: Maybe do `ls */` to be sure you're giving coherent input to `cd`.

Comment: Using the same idea, another option could be something like this: `find ~/projects/git/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec realpath {} \; | parallel "cd {} && git pull"`
`

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.git' -exec sh -c 'cd "{}" && pwd && git pull' \;
```

Comment: removing the `-maxdepth 1` flag, this is the only command I've found in a lot of searching and trying that executes a command _recursively_ (in all subdirectories, not just the directories one level down).

Answer (score 2):

To do it without using `find` but `forloop`

```
for dir in ~/projects/git/*/*/; do (cd "$dir" && git pull); done
```

Comment: That is not recursive, it just shows things that are two levels deep.

Comment: that is correct, thank you.